# Decode large Base64 strings

Tags: c#, base64, out-of-memory

I have an input string from a WebService in the form of a roughly 70 MB large base64-encoded string.

I want to decode this into a file, and tried the obvious: using `Convert.FromBase64String()`.

This, however, yields a `OutOfMemoryException`. After some reading, I discovered that the `Convert` methods concerned with Base64

> leak memory (no doubt due to the immutable nature of strings and some poor design inside the framework methods)
>   *[source](http://www.tribridge.com/knowledge-center/tribridge/posts/p2/2011/04/29/solving-outofmemoryexception-errors-when-attempting-to-attach-large-base64-encoded-content-into-crm-annotations)*

and there is a handy "streamed" replacement in the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace: `FromBase64Transform`.

So, I decided to give that a try, but I need to input the method an array of `byte`s, which I don't have - I have a string.

How can I convert the `string` I have into `byte`s without running into another `OutOfMemoryException` on *that* transformation again?

Comment: The Large Object Heap is notoriously poorly understood.  There are exceedingly few reasons left today to not run a web service on a 64-bit operating system.  Standard mistake is to forget to remove the jitter forcing, Project + Properties, Compile tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you probably could turn your string into a byte array in memory without worrying about memory usage, here's how you can *stream* the transformation:

```
var input = "abcdefghijklmnop";
byte[] output;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, new FromBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
using (var tr = new StreamWriter(cs))
{
    tr.Write(input);
    tr.Flush();
    output = ms.ToArray();
}
```

If you replace the `MemoryStream` with a suitable `FileStream` you can stream directly to file rather than an array:

```
var input = new string('a', 400000000);
byte[] output;
using (var ms = new FileStream(Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".bin", FileMode.Create))
using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, new FromBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
using (var tr = new StreamWriter(cs))
{
    tr.Write(input);
    tr.Flush();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()` or similar to convert your string back to the original ASCII which was used to transmit the base64-encoded data.

I am curious about how you received the string from the `WebService` in the first place. Is it possible that you can skip the conversion to a .NET string and just pass the bytes received directly to the transform? That would be more efficient.

Comment: The response is a JSON response, which is deserialized using `NewtonSoft.Json` - It returns a proper object. But I guess I will have to create some exception for this type of response, so I can stream the response directly...

Comment: That would certainly be better. Though, to be fair: the main reason to use base64 is to deal with scenarios where you can't stream binary, e.g due to format issues, API limitations, etc. If what you've got is JSON, it might be more trouble than it's worth to add streaming support (but if you do think it's worth it, you can transmit binary and save 25% on your bandwidth :) ).

Comment: Unfortunately, the WebService is not under my control. I have to work with what I get from it.